# CSS :hover - why won't sub item appear?

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors

I can't work out what is wrong with my :hover CSS to make a sub item appear.

```
p:hover #main-navigation{display:block;}
```

The **#main-navigation** is set to display:none, so the code above shoul reset it back to visible?

Here's a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56cx8zwx/1/).

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```
p:hover + #main-navigation{ display:block; }
```

Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56cx8zwx/2/)

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why? Is it because the div isn't within the P tag?

Comment: Exactly, because the `p` and the `#main-navigation` elements are siblings. I've updated the answer to include a link to the relevent documentation.

Comment: Elements that are placed after the `p:hover` which is ` + #main-navigation` are also selected.

Comment: @Mike Ante: Yes, but you would need to go out of your way to achieve such a situation (namely, moving the id attribute out of the original #main-navigation, or worse, duplicating it), so it's probably not that much of a concern.

Comment: While my answer explains why it wasn't working as you expected, @BoltClock's answer also explains the problems that occur in your case.

Answer (score 4):

`#main-navigation` is not a descendant of the `p`, but a sibling (for that matter a `div` can never be a descendant of a `p` anyway). Here's the markup from your fiddle with some changes to its indentation to make this clearer:

```
<div id="menuWrapper">
    <p>hover me to see the menu</p>
    <div id="main-navigation">
        <!-- ul id="menu" ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The direct but naïve answer to this is to replace the descendant selector with a sibling selector:

```
p:hover+#main-navigation{display:block;}
```

However [as you can see](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/56cx8zwx/3), once your cursor leaves the `p`, `#main-navigation` will disappear, preventing the user from ever being able to access `#main-navigation`.

I recommend moving the `:hover` to the wrapper element instead:

```
#menuWrapper:hover #main-navigation{display:block;}
```

That way, [the cursor is able to access `#main-navigation`](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/56cx8zwx/4), while still remaining within the content area of the wrapper for the purposes of `:hover`. The `p` element can remain as is, since it represents the label text.